# How to remove songs which has 0 duration in cursor in android

Tags: android, listview, duration, android-cursor

I am creating Music app. I use cursor to display songs in the list view. I don't know how to remove songs which have duration 0 from cursor.

This is my code which displays all songs in listview.

```
    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
        super(context, layout, c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname, R.id.title, R.id.duration});
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        long durationInMs = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        name.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));


        Duration d = new Duration();

        String durationInMin = d.convertDuration(durationInMs);

        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);

        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: The adapter is not really the place to remove items (and you can't really "remove" rows of a Cursor). It would be better if the query you used to retrieve the Cursor in the first place includes a WHERE clause that excludes anything with a duration <= 0.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by adding where clause (MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION+">0" in my code) in contentResolver.query method like this :

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION+">0", null, sortOrder);
```